# Numeration of formulas in Lyx

Tags: pdftex, lyx

How to numerate formulas in Lyx? Is there exist LaTeX command like "\tag "? I haven't found corresponding info before.

Comment: Well you can do it easily with the environment `equation` no need to add tags as long as you are satisfied with the automatic numbering. In other case you should use the `\tag{}` command loading in the preamble before the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @Aradnix That comment is only semi-useful, as the OP uses LyX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. OP?

Comment: @Aradnix 'Original poster', i.e. PhysiXxx.

Comment: PhysiXxx: see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83531/numbering-equations-with-lyx/85145#85145 answers your questions. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57948/automatic-equation-numbering-in-lyx/57981#57981

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say formulas, I assume you mean formulas in a display: `Insert > Math > Display Formula` (there is a keyboard shortcut, but I don't remember what the default is). These are LaTeX `\[ \]` environments, and become `\equation` environments upon labeling or numbering.

Once you have inserted your display, you **right-click the display** and may from there choose to number it or label it for cross-reference. Again, keyboard shortcuts exist.

PS. If you want an `\align` environment, `Shift + Enter` with the cursor in the display, then number lines (e.g. by right-clicking).