# Automatically index bold terms in lyx

Tags: lyx, indexing

I'm writing a document in LyX and I whish to auto-index all the terms in bold.

I'm using the Insert -> Index Entry every time I need to index a word, but since I don't require special modifications in the index, I'd be glad to avoid to do 2 operations instead of just one.

So, I'd like to have a command, something that can be inserted quickly (with a short-cut, like selecting words of interest and pressing a button) which will make one or more words in bold AND placing them in index.

Please note that I need to handle multiple words or short phrases in the index.

How can I achieve this result?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a new keyboard shortcut (see, e.g., [Shortcuts for Lemma, Claim, Theorem etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39779/shortcuts-for-lemma-claim-theorem-etc/39965#39965)) with the function

```
command-sequence font-bold;index-insert
```

that will let you select a word/words and make them bold and indexed. It won't let you press the shortcut and then type the word though (I don't know how to do that).

Comment: Nice, actually it's ok like this, as usually I write, then select, then apply a modification. TY! :)