# How to make keyboard shortcut that do more then one thing

Tags: lyx

In LyX, how to make a keyboard shortcut that make more then one thing?
e.g. **Bold** + *Italic*...

Thank you!

Comment: You would probably get a better answer in superuser https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lyx

Comment: Can you explain me please about this community? Thank you!!

Comment: @percusse Well, there have been plenty of similar questions here as well. It might be borderline though. heblyx: You're after `command-sequence` I believe, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60083/automatically-index-bold-terms-in-lyx/60093#60093

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes probably. By the way, I didn't mean to sound as this question is off-topic but over there they are really good with software tinkering in general.