# Numbering all equations

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

How can I number the equations of a document all at once?

I've tried to find an option in LyX but I didn't find any.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83531/numbering-equations-with-lyx/85145#85145 helps.

Comment: how are equations now entered?  if they are entered with `\[ ... \]` then there are two (not necessarily lyx) ways to get them all numbered:  with latex definitions `\renewcommand{\[}{\begin{equation}} \renewcommand{\]}{\end{equation}}` or by editing to change all `\[` to `\begin{equation}` and all `\]` to `\end{equation}`.  only `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` generates a number for a displayed equation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Comment: @barbarabeeton LyX uses `\[ .. \]` for 'standard' displayed math, you have to specify manually if you want numbering, in which case it switches to `equation`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- thanks.  i didn't know that.  you should be able to answer this then, if it hasn't already been answered elsewhere.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It has I think, see my first comment above.