# How to make a shortcut for a \displaystyle?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, displaystyle

I want to make a shortcut at LyX that if I press it I'll get what the `\displaystyle` does (in math mode).

e.g.: If I'll press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>  I'll get an integral...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can at least make a shortcut to insert just `\displaystyle`, if that is OK. Go to Tools --> Preferences --> Editing --> Shortcuts (see [Shortcuts for Lemma, Claim, Theorem etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39779/shortcuts-for-lemma-claim-theorem-etc/39965#39965) for a screenshot). Click *New*, and in the Function field write

```
math-size \displaystyle
```

Enter whichever shortcut you would like. If the shortcut already exists, LyX will inform you of this, and you have to either choose a new shortcut, or edit the existing command.

Comment: Thank you!!
And I can make a shortcut to insert to math mode at `\displaystyle`?

Comment: @YoavFridman Ctrl + M will enter inline math mode, so you could do Ctrl + M followed by your new shortcut. To make a shortcut that enters inline math mode and inserts `\displaystyle`, use the function `command-sequence math-mode; math-size \displaystyle`, but that will not be ideal if you use it when already in math-mode.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
You helped me a lot!!
LyX is really great software!!