# How to make a shortcut for \mathbb font in LyX?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I want to make a shortcut for the `\mathbb` font (or other fonts) in LyX.
How can I do it?

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Jubobs - Thank you! Hope someone will answer!

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you want.  many authors define commands for single letters in particular fonts, for example, a blackboard bold R might be defined as `\newcommand{\bbR}{\mathbb{R}}`, or for a fraktur M `\newcommand{\frM}{\mathfrak{M}}`.  this, of course, is not specific to lyx.

Comment: Are you talking about "keyboard shortcuts"?

Comment: @karlkoeller - yes...

Comment: You add new shortcuts as described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39779/shortcuts-for-lemma-claim-theorem-etc/39965#39965. The function you need is `math-insert \mathbb`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thank you so much!!! you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New shortcuts are added under Tools --> Preferences --> Editing --> Shortcuts, for details see [Shortcuts for Lemma, Claim, Theorem etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39779/shortcuts-for-lemma-claim-theorem-etc/39965#39965). The function you need for the blackboard font is

```
math-insert \mathbb
```

The other fonts in the list (under the font button on the math toolbar) has similar functions, just replace `\mathbb` with the appropriate macro, e.g. `math-insert \mathcal`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could go to [User]/AppData/Roaming/LyX[version]/bind (on Mac or Linux the path would differ), open `user.bind` with a text editor and insert the following line:

```
\bind "M-k b" "command-sequence math-insert `\\mathbb`;"
```

Which would insert a `\\mathbb` environment on pressing `alt+k b`.

You could also use

```
\bind "M-k r" "command-sequence math-insert \\mathbb R; char-right"
\bind "M-k z" "command-sequence math-insert \\mathbb Z; char-right"
```

Which would insert `\\mathbb{R}` and `\\mathbb{Z}`, respectively, and move your pointer out of `\\mathbb` environment.